# Removing vertical lines in tables

Tags: tables

I have the following table.

[image]

1. How can I remove extra falling lines?
2. How can I make a double line between R43 and R44?

Here is my MWE.

```
\documentclass[12pt,landscape]{article}

\usepackage[top=20mm,bottom=20mm,left=20mm,right=20mm,marginparwidth=30mm,marginparsep=1mm]{geometry}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[htb]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
    \textbf{C1} & \textbf{C2} & \textbf{C3} & \textbf{C4} & \textbf{C5} \\ \hline
    R11 & R21 & R31 & R41 & R51 \\
    R12 & R22 & R32 & R42 & R52 \\ \cline{1-1}
    R13 & R23 & R33 & R43 & R53 \\  \cline{4-4}
    R14 & R24 & R34 & R44 & R54 \\ \cline{1-3}  \cline{5-5}
    ~ & R25 & R35 & R56 & R55 \\ \cline{4-4}
    ~ & R26 & R36 & ~ & R56 \\
    ~ & R27 & R37 & ~ & R57 \\
    ~ & R28 & R38 & ~ & R58 \\ \cline{2-3} \cline{5-5}
    ~ & R29 & ~ & ~ & R59 \\
    ~ & R210 & ~ & ~ & R510 \\ \cline{2-2} \cline{5-5}
    ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & R511 \\
    ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & R512 \\
    ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & R513 \\ \cline{5-5}
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Unusual Table}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[top=20mm,bottom=20mm,left=20mm,right=20mm,
            marginparwidth=30mm,marginparsep=1mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hhline}
\newcommand\mc{\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}}
\newcommand\mcc{\multicolumn{2}{c|}{}}
\newcommand\mcccc{\multicolumn{4}{c|}{}}
\begin{document}


\begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
    \textbf{C1} & \textbf{C2} & \textbf{C3} & \textbf{C4} & \textbf{C5} \\ \hline
R11     & R21 & R31 & R41   & R51 \\
R12     & R22 & R32 & R42   & R52 \\    \cline{1-1}
R13     & R23 & R33 & R43   & R53 \\    \hhline{|~|~|~|=|~|} %\cline{4-4}
R14     & R24 & R34 & R44   & R54 \\    \cline{1-3} \cline{5-5}
\mc     & R25 & R35 & R56   & R55 \\    \cline{4-4} 
\mc     & R26 & R36 & \mc   & R56 \\
\mc     & R27 & R37 & \mc   & R57 \\
\mc     & R28 & R38 & \mc   & R58 \\ \cline{2-3} \cline{5-5}
\mc     & R29 &  \mcc       & R59 \\
\mc     & R210 & \mcc       & R510 \\ \cline{2-2} \cline{5-5}
\mcccc                      & R512 \\
\mcccc                      & R513 \\ \cline{5-5}
  \end{tabular}
\caption{Unusual Table}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```